# Functional equation : prove a property of the solution

Tags: functional-analysis

Let the equation be $f (a,b)=\int_\Omega g(a,x)g(b,x)dx $

If the condition on f is : $f (a,b)=h (a-b) $ can we prove that $g (a,x) $ is of the form $k (a-x) $ ?

Comment: Is the RHS a definite integral? If so, what are the upper and lower bounds?

Comment: Yes it's a definite integral. I forgot to add that h is $2\pi $-periodical.